Extensional sets in Coq and induction
I would like to define the following data type in Coq:
Inductive X : Type :=
| constr : FinSet X -> X.
Here constr should take a single argument, which is a finite set of elements of X. I need this set to be extensional, so that constr S1 and constr S2 are definitionally equal whenever S1 and S2 have the same elements.
But this introduces a problem: usual implementations of extensional sets such as gset require some assumptions on the underlying type X, such as having a decidable order or being countable. Using these in lieu of FinSet leads to a type error, as the type X has not yet been defined. Is there a way to fix this?
Edit, since I cannot comment: I do not really care about the implementation being efficient, since the sets will be fairly small.

Do you care about the representation of finite sets being efficient in some way?

Indeed, what you want to do is not directly possible: defining an inductive type mutually with a function out of it (here, the order-deciding function), is a complex type-theoretic feature known as induction-recursion, which is not available in Coq. Even if it were, this would mean you would have to prove all the properties needed by your finite set interface mutually with the definition of X, which sounds like a horrible thing. And even if you were able to do that, you would end up with a very nasted nested inductive type (a datatype X where X appears recursively as an argument to a constructor, inside another datatype), whose reasonable status is not at all obvious.
Let me suggest another approach. (In what comes, I'll use slightly idealized Coq syntax, which you can probably emulate with good enough type-classes or a similar mechanism).
To fix things, let me try to give a reasonable specification for your problem. You want:

a property good_for_set : Type -> Prop
a type FinSet : forall X : Type, good_for_set X -> Type (I'll omit the second argument in what comes next)
with a bunch of operations and properties
including a membership predicate InSet : X -> FinSet X -> Prop, that is extensional: forall (S S' : FinSet X), (forall x, InSet x S <-> InSet x S') -> S = S'
a type I : Type, with an operation constr : FinSet I -> I
with an induction property, something like

forall (P : I -> Prop),
(forall (S : FinSet I), (forall i : I, InSet i S -> P i) -> P (constr S)) ->
forall i : I, P i

While I don't think you can easily construct I directly as an inductive type (due to the issues above), I believe there is a satisfactory path, albeit a rather involved one.
Finite Sets
First, implement your FinSet as sorted lists. For this, you need your carrier type to have decidable equality, and a decidable total preorder (this is what good_for_set contains). From this, you can build sorted : list X -> bool, and
Record FinSet (X : Type) : Type := { car : list X ; sort : sorted car }.

(ssrbool gives you a coercion from bool to Prop so that you can simply write sorted car for the type of sort instead of sorted car = true.)
Crucially, because the second component is an equality of booleans, there is exactly one such equality, and you can show
forall S S' : FinSet X, S.(car) = S'.(car) -> S = S'

Moreover, on sorted lists equality is the same as membership, and so this implementation of FinSet is extensional.
The standard library contains a similar representation, see FSet. This is probably a bit old, does not show extensionality, and relies on modules which are yet another can of worm which you might want to avoid. But at least you can take inspiration from that.
Defining the type
Next, define
Inductive _I : Type :=
| _constr : list _I -> _I.

Coq's auto-generated induction principle for such nested data-types is garbage (in fact, I advise to Unset Elimination Schemes. so that it does not get generated at all, and to prove you own, involving Forall for lists).
Now from _I you can carve out the type I that you like. First, you can define an equality test on _I, and a strict total order (lexicographic ordering). Call an inhabitant i : _I "canonical" if it consists of canonical elements, and is sorted, that is
Fixpoint canonical (i : _I) : bool :=
  match i with
  | _constr l => forallb canonical l && sorted l
  end.

And finally define
Record I : Type := { i : _I ; can : canonical i }.

Just like for FinSet, since can is an equality of booleans, it is proof irrelevant, so the equality of two Is is the equality of the underlying _Is, which just as for FinSet will be extensional since they are canonical.
The initial algebra structure
Finally, with enough properties on sorted, you should be able to construct a constr : FinSet I -> I by building on _constr. And you should also be able to show that I actually satisfies the induction principle.
This is a long road, with quite a bit of advance type-theoretic trickery, and this is definitely more complicated than a plain old inductive type. But in the end I believe you should get something very close to your original intention, and that you can seal that away well-enough that in the later parts of your work you will not see all these complications.
